# CoreData sqlite3 db - populating timestamp column with python script

Tags: iphone, python, ios, sqlite, core-data

I have a coredata model backed by a sqllite db. I want to populate the db with some initial data.

I have been using Python to do this so far and it has been working well. The only bit that isn't working is inserting dates. I understand coredata stores dates in epoch format so I am currently inserting them via Python like this:

```
time.mktime(datetime(2012, 7, 1, 12, 30, 30).timetuple())
```

However, this doesn't give me the correct date when the data is loaded via coredata. Any ideas on how to format the date so it is read in correctly via coredata?

*NOTE:
I realise that most people recommend doing this via a small app that uses the same model rather than using a Python script, but I find the Python syntax more concise for constructing and inserting lots of objects.

**E.g.**
I can call methods that insert data like this:

```
insertData(con, 1, 1, 'Data 1', 'Description')
```

*vs Objective-C with its long-winded method calls:*

```
[self insertdata withCon:con id: 1 i2:1 val:@"Data 1", Desc:@"Description"];
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705062/behind-the-scenes-core-data-dates-stored-with-31-year-offset and see if that helps

Comment: I can do this: nsdate = dateCompleted - datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)    but then how to I convert this to something I can insert in to the sqlite timestamp column? This is the first time I am using python.

Comment: Ray Wenderlich has written a nice tutorial about how to do that. Refer [his blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data appears to use 1 January 2001, GMT as the reference date (same as the `NSDate` method `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`) and not 1970, as the `mktime` function in Python, so you'd have to calculate your timestamp based on that.

This is entirely undocumented of course, and I'd agree with [dpjanes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11382631/573626) that this approach is generally a bad idea.

If you really really want to do this, you could construct an appropriate timestamp in Python like this:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

ref = time.mktime(datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).timetuple())
now = time.time() - ref
```

Comment: And make sure the sqlite3 datetime column is declared as INTEGER as per section 1.2 here (http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: One would assume anyway! There's no rule that says CoreData has to implement datetime the way sqlite wants.

Comment: Though it doesn't really matter because SQLite uses dynamic column types, I think that a `REAL` would be more appropriate, as timestamps are `double`s in Cocoa.

Comment: So I got this working, thanks for the input guys. Doing a simple date - refdate gives a timedelta which my script complains about when I try to insert in to the timestamp column. If i call total_seconds() on this though it goes in fine and is correctly read in coredata without me having to mess with the db schema.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, don't do this. I use Python all the time to populate sqlite databases and read them with Objective-C and Java, but CoreData is something that *uses* sqlite but how it uses it may change over time.

> Because Core Data is not intended to be an ORM for sqlite, it cannot
>   read arbitrary sqlite schema. Conversely, you should not rely on being
>   able to read Core Data's sqlite data stores with other sqlite tools;
>   the schema is an implementation detail that may change.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/524301/96338

Comment: Yup I realise that as i said in my post. I am open to suggestions on alternatives that dont involve writing object construction in objective c which i find cumbersome and to explicit for this kind of thing.