# iOS Date (NSDate) in SQLite being read by Android

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, nsdate

From Android, I am reading SQLite3 Databases initially created from iOS (via **NSDate**). I can read the tables and values just fine, but there is a TIMESTAMP issue...

A **TIMESTAMP** field shows a numeric value, when viewed SQLite Database Browser.
For example, the value of **385192800** is found in the database, which I believe corresponds to Sun March 17 2013, 6:00 AM UTC/GMT+0.

How can I interpret this date for Android (Java)? Typcially, timestamps should be the number of seconds (or even milliseconds) from 1970-01-01. This date is not even close...

When I issue the query below, I get "1982-03-16"...

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datetime(385192800, 'unixepoch')) AS somedate 
FROM SOMETABLE LIMIT 1
```

It must not be a typical unix timestamp.. What does iOS's NSDate do, when persisting to SQLite3?

Comment: What happens when you Google for iOS timestamps and NSDate?

Comment: Didn't see the reference year of 2001. Spathi's link was also very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core data stores timestamps based on the reference date, which is 1st Jan 2001. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705062/behind-the-scenes-core-data-dates-stored-with-31-year-offset) for more information.

PS: Your question does not mention the year of the timestamp that you have specified.

Comment: Edit: Added the year (2013). Thanks!