# How to save the current date to CoreData?

Tags: swift, date, core-data

I have an attribute in CoreData which accepts a date value. I just want to get the current date and save it in this format "dd/mm/yyyy" . But don't know how. Thanks

Comment: CoreData can store `Date` objects natively. You shouldn't have to translate to a standard `String` format when going between your application and the database. For example, in my project I have some entities with properties of type `Date` which are declared in the `NSManagedObject` subclass as `@NSManaged var date: Date?`. They can be accessed directly without having to bother with any `String` conversions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're storing it as Date, then you have no control over the format until you try to present the returned value somewhere, and you just store `Date()`

If you're storing it as shown, then you need to use a DateFormatter to create the string you need

Comment: So when i set the value to save i just use "Date()" ?

Comment: Yes - https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/date/1780470-init

The value will be stored in Date format - not 'dd/mm/yyyy', so if you want to display it like that, you need to format it before you use it later

Comment: So i would just format it when i get it back from core-data?

Comment: Yes - just like @Rock-Balbao has shown in his answer

Answer (score 3):

Here you can store date in coreData as shown in format

```
let date = NSDate()
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
var dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
```

> store **dateString** in your coreData

Comment: indeed, but the point is you can **either** store a Date value or a string representation of it.  You can't store a Date value with a format

Comment: @Russell I know. but the format he asked is in this format. So I gave him this answer. For another scenario he has your answer already

Answer (score 0):

To save dates in Core Data I have created the following extension

```
 extension Date {
     /**
      Formats a Date

      - parameters format: (String) for eg dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss
      */
     func format(format:String = "dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss") -> Date {
         let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
         dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
         let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: self)
         if let newDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
             return newDate
         } else {
             return self
         }
     }
 }
```

To set a date value of a field

```
 let date = Date()
 entity?.setValue(date.format(), forKey: "updated_at")
```

Note: You may see date saved as timestamp when you open your database. Please refer to the following issue [NSDate being saved as timestamp in CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861215/nsdate-being-saved-as-timestamp-in-coredata)

You can also pass you own date formats in the "format()" extension to get different types of dates in the application