# Timestamp with 9 digits in SQLite file

Tags: sqlite, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am working on a SQLite file from a client and found a column marked as TIMESTAMP, I have work in the past with php timestamp with 10 digits, this file has time stamps with 9 digits to the left and 6 to the right:

```
570822838.260406
570822838.544408
570822846.167604
```

I do not know how to convert this numbers to date-times or how are they calculated. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know which date is represented by `570822838.260406`?

Comment: No, I now it could be March or April, thats all I know,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess it's an Apple Core Data timestamp, based on this:

```
sqlite> select datetime(570822838.260406, 'unixepoch', '+31 years');
2019-02-02 17:53:58
```

So you can use the above to convert to a standard format.

(Also, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705062/behind-the-scenes-core-data-dates-stored-with-31-year-offset) .)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.