# What date format is "623548800"?

Tags: sqlite, timestamp

I exported the SQLite db from an iOS app and was wanting to run a query based on the date, but I found that it's in a format I don't recognize. As stated above, the latest value is "623548800". I'm assuming this corresponds to today, since I created a record in the app today. This is 9 digits, so it's too short to be a Unix timestamp, which is 10 digits.

The earliest record in the db is "603244800", which likely corresponds to when I started using the app on 2/13/2020. That's a difference of 20,304,000, so it looks like it's using seconds, as it's been 20,312,837 seconds since then.

Is this essentially tracking seconds based on some proprietary date, or is this a known format?

Comment: Some math indicates an offset of..? Searching for that date yields..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dates are Unix Timestamps.
By using any on line converter (like https://www.epochconverter.com) you can find the dates they correspond to.

The latest value `623548800` corresponds to `Thursday, October 5, 1989 12:00:00 AM GMT`
and the earliest value `603244800` corresponds to `Sunday, February 12, 1989 12:00:00 AM GMT`.

So it seems like your dates or off by 31 years.
I found a similar case here: [Behind The Scenes: Core Data dates stored with 31 year offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10705062/10498828)

If you want you can convert them to the format `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'` like this:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET datecolumn = datetime(datecolumn, 'unixepoch', '+31 year')
```

or:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET datecolumn = date(datecolumn, 'unixepoch', '+31 year')
```

if you are not interested in the time part.

Comment: Thanks, yes, good idea just using that 31-year offset like that. In my case, I'm not concerned about the time of day, so the year offset will suit me just fine.

Answer (score 1):

623548800 - 603244800 = 20304000

20304000/86400 seconds in 24 hours = 235 days

October 5, 2020 - February 13, 2020 = 235 days

UTC Unix timestamp February 13, 2020 = 1581552000

Like the prior comment said it looks like an offset, it might be a timestamp somewhere in source or in db

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly!